# How to test for a `click` event on the icon button of the `material-ui` AppBar?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm testing the following [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) component:

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar'

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title='My NavBar Title'
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NavBar
```

It's composed of a [material-ui AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) component. Using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) and [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/index.html), I want to simulate a `click` on the `AppBar`'s `IconButton`:

```
import NavBar from './NavBar'
import React from 'react'
import test from 'tape'
import { /* I don't know if it's `shallow` or `mount` */ } from 'enzyme'

test('NavBar component test', (assert) => {
  test('simulating a click on the icon button', (assert) =>
    // How do I do this?
    // The following results in error:
    // const wrapper = shallow(<NavBar />)
    // wrapper.find('AppBar').find('IconButton').simulate('click')
    assert.end()
  })
  assert.end()
})
```

How can I do it properly?

Obs: I'm searching for `IconButton` because, according to the [React Dev Tools](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html) tab, that's the name of the rendered icon button component.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mount` for testing components below the top level of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to test whether the function is called, not using the `.simulate('event')`, just invoke the method directly.

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<NavBar />)
//use sinon.spy( object, method) to spy the method, instead of sinon.spy(func)
const spy = Sinon.spy(wrapper.renderer._instance._instance, 'click')
//inovke
wrapper.renderer._instance._instance.click()
expect(spy.called).to.be.true
```

You could find the method inside the `.renderer._instance` or its children _instance objects (depending on how deep the element is) and then use `sinon.spy` to spy this method.

I don't like this way, but this is the only way I know how to spy a method till now.

Comment: what if I wanted to pass props values to the child out of parent component ? @Webb Lu